# jQgrid: Disable checkbox and row (conditional)

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Based on `flag_status` passed from PHP data array, I need to disable the row and checkbox. Additionally prevent selection of disabled rows to support `select all` checkbox in the header of the multiselect column

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
    url:call_url,
        datatype: "json",
    height: 'auto',
    rowNum: 20,
    rowList: [20,30,40],
    colNames:[<?php echo $col;?>],
    colModel:[
                {name:'USER_ID',index:'USER_ID', align:'center',search:false,hidden:true,key:true},
        {name:'PROJECT_NAME',index:'PROJECT_NAME', align:'center',search:false,hidden: true},
        {name:'EMP_NAME',index:'EMP_NAME', sortable:true,summaryType:'count',summaryTpl : 'Total ({0}) Resource Hours' },
        <?php for($i=1;$i<=count($cal_arr);$i++) {?>
        {name:'<?php echo $i;?>',index:'<?php echo $i;?>',search:false,align:"center",sortable:false ,width:80 },
        <?php } ?>
    ],
    pager: "#page",
        multiselect: true,
    shrinkToFit :true,
    autowidth: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    grouping: true, 
    groupingView : { groupField : ['PROJECT_NAME'], 
                    groupColumnShow : [false], 
                    groupText : ['<b>{0}</b>'],
                    groupCollapse : false, 
                    groupOrder: ['asc'], 
                    groupSummary : [true], 
                    showSummaryOnHide: true,
                    groupDataSorted : true },
    sortname: 'EMP_NAME',
    caption: "Programatically block selection of some grid row',
    gridComplete: function () {
                    var recs = $("#grid").getGridParam("records");
                    $( ".mycontent" ).remove();
                    if (recs == 0 || recs == null) {
                        $('#grid').after("<div class='mycontent' style='color:red;text-align:center'>No Record Found</div>");
                        $("#btn_submit").hide();
                    }
            },


            loadComplete: function() {
                // we make all even rows "protected", so that will be not selectable
                var cbs = $("tr.jqgrow > td > input.cbox:even", jQuery("#grid")[0]);
                cbs.attr("disabled", "disabled");
            },
            beforeSelectRow: function(rowid, e) {
                var cbsdis = $("tr#"+rowid+".jqgrow > td > input.cbox:disabled", jQuery("#grid")[0]);
                if (cbsdis.length === 0) {
                    return true;    // allow select the row
                } else {
                    return false;   // not allow select the row
                }
            },
            onSelectAll: function(aRowids,status) {
                if (status) {
                    // uncheck "protected" rows
                    var cbs = $("tr.jqgrow > td > input.cbox:disabled", jQuery("#grid")[0]);
                    cbs.removeAttr("checked");

                    //modify the selarrrow parameter
                    jQuery("#grid")[0].p.selarrrow = jQuery("#grid").find("tr.jqgrow:has(td > input.cbox:checked)")
                        .map(function() { return this.id; }) // convert to set of ids
                        .get(); // convert to instance of Array
                }
            }

})
```

Thanks to @Oleg for small [demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DataToMultiSelect2Blocked.htm), but does not completely meet the below requirements.

Can not use `key:true` for `flag_status` since its bieng used for `user_id`

Here it disables all even rows, so that will be not selectable, but need to disable only if value of `flag_status = 1`. How to pass that value in jQgrid and disable row (adding class `ui-state-disabled`) and prevent checkbox being selected (making it disabled too) ?

HTML structure:

```
<tr class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" tabindex="-1" id="13234" role="row" aria-selected="false">
<td aria-describedby="grid_cb" style="text-align:center;width: 20px;" role="gridcell">
<input type="checkbox" name="jqg_grid_13234" class="cbox" id="jqg_grid_13234" role="checkbox" disabled="disabled">
</td>
</tr>
```

Here `USER_ID` is set on `<tr>` and `<input>`, instead `flag_status` should set on `<tr>` and `USER_ID` on `<input>`. If flag_status value is `1`, class `ui-state-disabled` should be added to that `<tr>` making the `<input>` disabled.

Version - `jqGrid  4.6.0`

Comment: Which `datatype` you use in jqGrid? If you load the data via Ajax (`datatype` is `"json"` or `"xml"`) then another question: do you use `loadonce: true` or not? In other words it's important to know whether you have *local* `data` in the grid or not? You write about `key:true` and about `user_id`, but you not posted any grid definition (no `colModel` and no test data). It's important to know **which fork or jqGrid (old jqGrid till 4.7, [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) or [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)) and which version you use**?

Comment: @Oleg, pls find updated question content with more details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My demo which you referenced is already really old. I modified it to [the following](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DataToMultiSelect2Blocked_.htm) which more corresponds your requirements.

I uses in the demo

```js
rowattr: function (item) {
    if (parseInt(item.ID, 10) % 3 === 0) {
        return {"class": "ui-state-disabled ui-jqgrid-disablePointerEvents"};
    }
},
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").hasClass("ui-state-disabled")) {
        return false;   // not allow select the row
    }
    return true;    // allow select the row
}
```

where there are the following CSS rule for the class `ui-jqgrid-disablePointerEvents`:

```css
.ui-jqgrid-disablePointerEvents {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

You can easy modify the code of `rowattr` so that you disable the rows based on the value of `item.flag_status` instead of `item.ID` which I uses in the above demo.

Comment: Oleg: `pointer-events: none;` disables row click. How can I disable only checkbox, while keeping all hyperlinks clickable ?

Comment: And it would be great if you could explain why not using `loadComplete` and `onSelectAll`

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy: `rowattr` si more effective as `loadComplete`. Setting the class `ui-state-disabled` informs selectAll don't select the rows (see [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.base.js#L2533) for example). So no additional `onSelectAll` is required. About disabling the row you wrote yourself in your question (see "disable row (adding class ui-state-disabled)"). If you need allow clicks inside of the rows then you should be go back to the old code it will be more slowly, but it will work.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy: The usage of `flag_status` inside of `beforeSelectRow` without creating hidden row with the data or saving the information in `data-flag_status` of the row or some cell seems me impossible. You should decide where you need to hold the information during filling the grid. The quick&dirty, but easy working, solution you get by adding hidden `flag_status` column and the usage of `getCell` to get the data from the column inside of `beforeSelectRow`.

Comment: Oleg: Thanks for the detailed explaination. I really appreciate. Yes I need to disable the row as in grey out, but in that row, checkbox must not be selectable while if any links exists in that row, should be clickable.